# How can I know which git branch triggered my ADO pipeline?

Tags: git, triggers, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm looking to have different stages of my ADO pipeline run depending on the outcome of a condition. For this condition, I want to compare the name of the branch (the one that triggered the pipeline to run) up against a string literal. I can't do this until I can access the name of this branch in a dynamic way.

For example, I don't want my production stage to run, unless the branch that triggered the stage is named `master`.

I am familiar with the predefined variable `Build.Repository.Name` being used to get the name of the repository, but what I really need is the name of the *branch* in that repository that triggered the pipeline.

So, is there a variable that holds my triggering branch's name? and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found the solution to my problem in Microsoft's Azure Pipeline documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables)

> `Build.SourceBranch`
>
> The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. Some examples:
>
> Git repo branch: `refs/heads/master`
>
> Git repo pull request: `refs/pull/1/merge`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT of course. It does take 48 hours to be able to accept your own answer.